# set text in textview with text from an edittext in another class

Tags: android, class, text, textview, android-edittext

Im completely new to Android so apologies if this is a silly question. But my problem is this:

I have created a number of classes for each of the pages in my app and I would like to update the text in a textview of a particular class from the text in an edittext field from another class.

To be more specific, I have a login page and I want the username (input by the user in an edittext box) to be transferred to a textfield in the logged in page. Currently I am trying to achieve this by using a click listener for the log in button in the log in page:

```
public void sign_in_click(View view) {
    EditText tv1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_input_uname);

    String username=tv1.getText().toString();

    LoginDetails unamede=new LoginDetails();
    unamede.setuname(username);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), customer.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 

}
```

So the click listener initialises a new class variable I have defined in another class like so:

```
public class LoginDetails {
public String uname;

public void setuname(String username){
        uname=username;     
}

public String getuname(){
    return uname;   
}
}
```

and it gives uname the username from the edittext box in the login page.

Then I have in the logged in page under oncreate:

```
LoginDetails unamed= LoginDetails();
String username=unamed.getuname();

tv1.setText(username);
```

but the text in the textview box doesnt get anything written to it. Now I wont be surprised if I'm doing this completely wrong but any advice would be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: oops yeah forgot about that. sorry. accepted now

Comment: No problem. I only wanted to give a hint that it's a good habit to accept answers to indicate what worked for you so other people know and to honor the effort of of someone who gave you the right answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i would suggest is put the user's log in information into a SharedPreference. To transfer the date to another activity.

For example...

```
 SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("USER_INFO", 0);
 myPrefsEdit.putString("USER_ID", username=tv1.getText().toString(););
 //This is the username you get from edittext

 myPrefsEdit.putString("PASSWORD", password);
 //this is the user password you get from edittext

 myPrefsEdit.commit();
```

In your next activity.

Get reference to your SharePreference like...

```
SharedPreferences info = getSharedPreferences("USER_INFO, 0);
String username = info.getString("USER_ID", "DOESNT EXIST");
String userpassword = info.getString("PASSWORD", "DOESNT EXIST");
```

This should do it

Comment: Where you see "doesnt exist" in the code is what happens if the user_id isnt there. You can put anything you want here. Or you could set it to null. And test to see if the username == null and if so launch a AlertDialog telling the user to log in.

Comment: thanks for the response. I will certainly try this method. On a slightly different (but closely related) note is it not possible to refer to a view (e.g. textbox, edittext etc.) from another activity just by using its id? if not, what exactly is the point of the r.id file? it has the id's for all the elements I use in my app but I can only refer to the element with its id from the activity it is placed in? this seems silly to me

Comment: This is the way android is built. If you reference a view in a activity the layout MUST contain the widget or layout you r.id in your activity.

Comment: ok got it to work. needed an extra line of code from what you suggested. The putString method doesnt work directly for SharedPreferences objects so I had to create a SharedPrefernce.Editor object to allow me to edit the SharedPrefence items. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the username to activity intent extra (when you don't want to persist it in the shared preferenced right now):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), customer.class);
myIntent.putExtra("uname", username);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

And then in onCreate:

```
tv1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("uname"));
```

Comment: This could be good too..SharedPreference is more persistent and reliable as well.

Comment: thanks for response. coder_for_life22's method works fine so i'll stick with that for this particular problem. But im sure what you have suggested will come in handy somewhere else in the app. so thanks again.